# Android finish error

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Just started with some basic android development and I made a little menu with 3 buttons.

One of them is a quit button (I know that the finish activity doesn't really quit the application) but when I call it it closes the application and gives me a error saying that the application has stopped unexpectedly.

My code :

```
package darksea.game;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DarkSeaActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void ExitGameEvent()
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

The ExitGameEvent is linked to the button through xml.

Any thought on why it gives this error ?

Comment: Need to see more code. What you have posted will work fine.

Comment: This is all the code I have, and where can I find logCat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click handler [needs to take a View](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html) as an argument for it to be valid to be called from XML. Try:

```
public void ExitGameEvent(View v)
    {
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response this worked perfectly. As soon as the 5 min timer expires I'll add this as the answer

Comment: I mean keep accepting the answers, so that u will get quick responses. Goodluck :)